# Ubuntu 18.04 libicudata.so.58 cannot open

Tags: ubuntu, server, vps

I'm trying to install composer on my Ubuntu server and get the following error while trying to download and execute the composer setup file, and when checking the php version:

```
root@hosting:/# php -v
php: error while loading shared libraries: libicudata.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've looked on the internet but I can't find a solution?

My ubuntu details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```